# How to load Base64 RSA keys in Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, crypto++

I'm trying to write helper functions for a program I'm making and I need to return the keys as strings. Found a way to convert the RSA keys from PrivateKey/PublicKey to Base64 string.

```cpp
int main()
{
    //Generate params
    AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
    InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.Initialize(rng, 4096);

    //Generate Keys
    RSA::PrivateKey privKey(params);
    RSA::PublicKey pubKey(params);

    //Encode keys to Base64
    string encodedPriv, encodedPub;

    Base64Encoder privKeySink(new StringSink(encodedPriv));
    privKey.DEREncode(privKeySink);

    Base64Encoder pubKeySink(new StringSink(encodedPub));
    privKey.DEREncode(pubKeySink);

    RSA::PrivateKey pvKeyDecoded;
    RSA::PublicKey pbKeyDecoded;

    //how to decode...

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, how do I load the encoded keys back? I wasn't able to find any information on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> RSA::PrivateKey pvKeyDecoded;
> RSA::PublicKey pbKeyDecoded;
>
> //how to decode...
> ```

You can do something like:

```
StringSource ss(encodedPriv, true, new Base64Decoder);
pvKeyDecoded.BERDecode(ss);
```

---

You should also fix this:

```
Base64Encoder pubKeySink(new StringSink(encodedPub));
privKey.DEREncode(pubKeySink);  // pubKey.DEREncode
```

And you should call `MessageEnd()` once the key is written:

```
Base64Encoder privKeySink(new StringSink(encodedPriv));
privKey.DEREncode(privKeySink);
privKeySink.MessageEnd();

Base64Encoder pubKeySink(new StringSink(encodedPub));
pubKey.DEREncode(pubKeySink);
pubKeySink.MessageEnd();
```

You might also find [Keys and Formats](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) helpful from the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: I did try that before, from Keys And Formats link and all I'm getting is BER decode error Exception. In fact I tried almost all of the stuff from the wiki but at no avail. That's why I asked for help here.

I did try it again and it didn't work.

Comment: @Kyojin - see the edits above. Next time, please ask a concise question. Your question asked how to load a Base64 encoded key. You did not state you experienced an exception with code that was not provided.

Comment: Thanks it works! Sorry for not mentioning the exception. Will try to ask better next time.